# Objective-c array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I am slightly confused as I am using this piece of code;

```
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/Volumes/" error:nil];

int arraysize = sizeof dirContents;
```

to get an array of the contents of the "Volumes" direcoty, however when I output the array size it says that the array has 8 entries when there are only 4 files in that directory? This wouldn't be a problem but since I am using a for loop as soon as I get to;

```
NSString *volume1 = [dirContents objectAtIndex:4];
```

(4 being the value in the for loop) the application crashes and refuses to launch?

Thanks for any help

Comment: `sizeof dirContents` tells you that the ***pointer*** "dirContents" is eight bytes long.  Has absolutely nothing to do with the array itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `int arraysize = [dirContents count]` to get the correct size.

`sizeof` is a c-style operator that will not work correctly on Objective-C objects.

Comment: Thanks, that worked but I am curios why does the way I found on the web not work?

Comment: because sizeof returns the length of the pointer to the Objective-C object in memory. Just the size of the pointer not the object, and certainly not the size/count of the NSArray.

Comment: sizeof will give you the size of NSArray*. sizeof pointer being 8 means you're compiling for 64 bit platform

Comment: Ah, I do forget about that :-)

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` does not returns the length of the array but the size your variable occupies in memory. Since `dirContents` is a pointer it occupies only 8 byte.

To get the length of the array you should use

```
[dirContents count];
```

Besides, in arrays, objects are stored with indexes starting from 0. Thus, if your array has only 4 elements, `[dirContents objectAtIndex:4]` will end in a runtime error, since you are trying to retrieve the element in the fifth position.

Answer (score 2):

sizeof is receiving the size of the pointer. Instead use `int arraysize = [dirContents count];`

Answer (score 2):

Taking `sizeof` is not the right way of finding the number of `NSArray` elements. Use `dirContents.count` instead.